# How do i use form.setFieldsValue() for form items inside an input group in antd

Tags: reactjs, antd

I'm currently trying to set the field values inside an Input.Group in a form in antd 4.17, but I've not been able to find a solution on their documentation. It seems like setFieldsValue is unable to use "NamePath"-Parameters like resetFields does.
For example `form.resetFields(["default","condition"])` allows me to reset said input whereas `form.setFieldsValue({["default","condtion]: "desiredValue"})` results in an error.

Any help is appreciated

```js
const [form] = Form.useForm()
...
    <Button onClick={() => form.setFieldsValue(???)}>Set Values</Button>
    <Form form = {form} >
        <Input.Group compact>
            <Form.Item name={["default", "condition"]}>
                {renderConditionComponent(defaultInput)} //Function that builds a Select
            </Form.Item>
            <Form.Item
                name={["default", "value"]}
            >
                {renderInputComponent(defaultInput)} //Function that builds a Datepicker, Input or InputNumber
            </Form.Item>
        </Input.Group>
    </Form>
```

Comment: you should setFieldsValue like this data structure. {default: {conditon: 'value you want', value: 'value you want'}}. you can use like this. https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-7hlrdv

Comment: Hi LeeKlaus, thanks for your comment, this way it works. if you post it as an answer, i can accept it.

Comment: i'm glad it helped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use form.resetFields. It takes an array of objects. In each object you can pass the following Fields:

```
name: InternalNamePath;
value: StoreValue;
touched: boolean;
validating: boolean;
errors: string[];
warnings: string[];
```

In Your case, you will set values as

```
form.setFields([{name:["default", "condition"], value: ... }])
```